# Python facebook chatbook download from google

Tags: urllib

I'm trying to program a python file that downloads google images, but gives the following error

> "C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Scripts Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Scripts Python/ChatBot.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Scripts Python/ChatBot.py", line 4, in 
>       from urllib import FancyURLopener
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'FancyURLopener' from 'urllib' (C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib__init__.py)

my code:

```
            import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson

# Define search term
searchTerm = "william shatner"

# Replace spaces ' ' in search term for '%20' in order to comply with request
searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(' ','%20')


# Start FancyURLopener with defined version
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener = MyOpener()

# Set count to 0
count= 0

for i in range(0,10):
    # Notice that the start changes for each iteration in order to request a new set of images for each loop
    url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?' + 'v=1.0&q='+searchTerm+'&start='+str(i*4)+'&userip=MyIP')
    print (url)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

    # Get results using JSON
    results = simplejson.load(response)
    data = results['responseData']
    dataInfo = data['results']

    # Iterate for each result and get unescaped url
    for myUrl in dataInfo:
        count = count + 1
        print (myUrl['unescapedUrl'])

        myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(count)+'.jpg')

    # Sleep for one second to prevent IP blocking from Google
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realize that your problem (and even your code) has nothing to do with bots, facebook, or the facebook chatbot api-- all the tags you used. To get the best answers to your questions, please take more care to narrow down your problem statement and tags.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `FancyURLopener` is not where you are looking for it. This is the correct import statement:

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
```